# Why fetch await is not waiting to file download

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, download, fetch

I'm trying to download an apk from a googleapi server using fetch (i cant use any plugins and due to cors problems the only solution was to use fetch instead ionic native http)

So apparently the await is not working because it's trying to save the file while the data stream is still going on (the file is 11Mb).

```
async saveApk(){
  this.blob = await this.download(this.url);
  let apk = new Blob([this.blob], {type:'application/vnd.android.package-archive'});
  this.file.writeFile(this.file.cacheDirectory, 'test.apk', apk, { replace: true});
}

async download(url){
  try {
    const request = new Request(url.slice(0, -5), {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      credentials: 'include'
    });
    let response = await fetch(request);
    let data = await response.blob();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

I've been three days trying to solve it but i can't find the flaw.

Comment: What is `this.file`, exactly?

Comment: Why is `this.blob` an object-property? The scope and lifetime of `blob` should be limited to the `saveApk` function, so using a non-local means you're probably leaking resources.

Comment: this.file is an instance of the @ionic-native plugin: File,

Comment: i've already corrected this.blob and it's not working